# How to send an email by 2010 workflow only if the person picker field have a person assigned?

Tags: 2010, workflow

I would like to send an auto notification to someone who's name is picked in a certain field. I would like to send only if someone is picked. So how can I check if the person picker's value is an existing person before I try to send the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something on the lines of. create a workflow variable (string) and pass through the people picker value.

then create an if condition to check if its not empty ;) if it isnt then create an email step. when setting the TO section select the dictionary -> workflow lookup -> select the people picker field in question, in my example i just used the modified by field and put it to return email.

1) create var and set its val to the people picker field inquestion
[image]

2) create an if function to check if not empty. if not email using the people picker field. Click on the image below for more info.
[image]

Comment: It is working very well!Thanks again for the fast and detailed response!

Comment: glad to see it working and happy to help :)